# Android. Передача переменной на несколько tabactivity

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Здравствуйте.

Я с помощью `intent` передаю данные переменной, введенные в `edittext`, на вторую активити и там с работаю с переменной, содержащей эти данные.

Подскажите, как передавать с первой активити эти данные сразу на три активити, две из которых используются в качестве вкладок (tabactivity)?

Как я понимаю, обычным `startActivity` так делать нельзя т к в этом случае открываются сразу все указанные активити и программа падает.

Я искал решение в интернете и наткнулся так же на использование `singleton`, но хорошего описания работы на русском языке не нашел. Можете еще поделиться ссылкой на русскоязычный ресурс или рассказать про принцип работы `singleton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `TabActivity`, как вкладки уже устарели. Сейчас для этого используются Фрагменты(`Fragment`)
2. В главной активити(`ActivityGroup`?) вы храните ссылки на дочерние активити? Если да, то определите у дочерних метод, принимающий нужную переменную, как параметр, и проводящий все нужные операции, и вызывайте этот метод в главной активити, где нужно передать в дочерние какое-либо значение. А если не храните, то сохраняйте, и сделайте, как описано выше.

Но я бы все-таки советовал не пользоваться "каменным топором", а перейти на использование фрагментов.

Comment: Я сам разобрался, но за подсказку фрагментов спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

WAT???)))

TabActivity - This class was deprecated in API level 13.

я думаю должно быть так - одна активность.
на первом фрагменте TextView и ввод данных. далее волшебную кнопку нажали и появились табы - которые и будут переключать 3 фрагмента(вместо активностей).
содержать данные от TextView должна активность и в свою очередь раздавать фрагментам по требованию.

по хорошему должен быть написан интерфейс с помощью которого этот механизм и будет реализован.
пример -

```
interface DataProvider{
  String getData()
}

class MainActivity extend Activity implements DataProvider{

private String data;
@Ovveride
public String getData(){
    return data;
}
}
```

у фрагментов

```
class TabFragment extend Fragment {
   private DataProvider provider;

   onAttach(Context ctx){
       if (ctx instancOf DataProvider){
           this.provider = ctx;
       }
   }

   onDetach(Context ctx){
       provider = null;
   }
}
}
```

ну и когда фрагменту нужно получить данные дергаем `provider.getData();`

так же можно реализовать и для двух активностей. на одной осуществляется ввод данных затем бросаем интент .
запускаем вторую.
и в данном случае вторая активность будет являться провайдером.

писал код прямо здесь так что на работоспособность не надейтесь)))